# Change Target Framework from 4.5 to 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I am trying to change the target framework from 4.5 to 4.0, I have changed the target framework on all of my projects and I have created a testing build with VS2015. 

 
I am trying to run the app in WIN7 with .NET 4.0 installed but the app crashes and the errors are System.IO.FileLoadException for mscorlib.dll and PresentationFramework.dll

 
Does anyone know how to fix it?

*More info* 

 
I have tried also:

1. to build with vs2012 but I cannot use vs2010 because I am using async from BCL package
2. to create new solution with new projects to target from the start 4.0 framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone out there that may have the same problem, be sure that you have installed the latest update for .NET framework, it worked after I have installed the update [kb2468871](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2468871)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is try to run a .NET 4.5 in WIndows 7, which *per default* utilizes .NET 4.0.

Choose: or to install .NET 4.5 in WIndows 7 (I don't know if it's possible) or downgrade your project to NET 4.

Comment: i have downgrade my project to .net 4.0 but it isn't working on win7. I don't want to use .net 4.5

Comment: Some functions are *only* present in NET 4.5 (and newest versions), not in NET 4.  Had you ever checked if all utilized functions exist in NET 4?

Comment: yes i have tried also to remove every .net framework installed in my win10(without anniversary update) computer and the app isn't crashing

Comment: I'm really confused.... Do you want to run in Windows 10/NET 4.5 app in Windows 7? You must be sure the program does not utilize any function of NET 4.5 - just set its properties to NET 4, compile it and copy to Win7. It must be enough.

Comment: the app was running alright on .net 4.5 on win7 and win10. now i want to make it work on .NET 4.0, i have done any necessary change but it will not work on win7 just on win10 (both os with only .net 4.0 installed)

Comment: The problem may be related to GAC area in Win7. Since the app runs either NET4/NET4.5 in Win 10 and only NET 4,5 in Win7, the problem is related to the Windows. GAC area is a common area where .NET resides. You may have a corrupted mscorlib there, or any other error related to this. Try to manually address the DLL into you project reference and set COPY TO OUTPUT DIRECTORY to force the DLL goes to the app folder.

Comment: i have tried to copy the mscorlib and presentationframework libs to the output folder but that doesn't change anything

Comment: Does your REFERENCE points to your APP folder? I mean, uncheck the default libs location and add the ones your had copied to the project's folders.

Comment: you can't do that for mscorlib but you can for presentation framework but it didn't worked

Comment: So... You have no choice unless check with .NET FIX UTILITIES if your NET4 libraries are corrupted in Windows 7. Since the code functions in WIn10 even using NET 4 but NOT in Windows 7, the problem *must* be related to the OS. I had some problems like this here and the *only* way was to reinstall the entire Windows 7 in machine.  Good luck...

Comment: that is not an option because i can't say to the customers that they have the problem if the app crashes to their computer.

Comment: Is it happening in many computers/users at this time? So, try to configure a VM or other machine with clean WIN7 + VS2010/VS2012 and compile there.

Comment: it isn't public yet because it isn't working on my 2 testing machines. i'm trying to do work with remote debugger to find out the real problem. something behind the presentationframework dll is the problem probably. thanks a lot for your time

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck!

Comment: after the remote debugging i show that the crash was happening on system.core that presentationframework was "calling" and i saw that it needed the latest update for the .NET framework. Thank again for your time.